# Why i see a commit using 'git show', but I don't see it in 'git log'?

Tags: git

I am able to see a commit using 'git show 9a6fe03'

But when I use 'git log' and search for '9a6fe03', I see nothing.

And when I do 'git grep 9a6fe03', it returns nothing too.

Can you please tell me why?

Thank you.

**Update**: I find my commit when I use
$git branch --all --contains 9a6fe03

git branch --all --contains 956ae03

```
  remotes/my-git/branch1
  remotes/my-git/branch2
  remotes/my-git/branch3
```

but I don't see anything when I do

```
git branch --contain 9a6fe03
```

I get nothing.

My question is which branch I am on now?
When I do '

```
 $ git branch
* (no branch)
```

I think I am on a stage called 'Detached head' 
but when when I do 'repo sync', I get commits from other people?

Comment: Different branch? Try `git log --all`.

Comment: Thanks. I see that when I do 'git log --all'. Now my question is how can I tell which branch 9a6fe03 is on?

Comment: `git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate` generally helps to get a nice overview.

Comment: but it just give me '| | | | | | * 9a6fe03 XXXXXXX' which does not tell me which branches has it.

Comment: `git branch --contains 9a6fe03` will tell you specifically which branch it's on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple questions, multiple answers. :)

**1. log vs. show vs. grep**

- `git show 9a6fe03` will show you that single commit. (Including the changes.)
- `git log 9a6fe03` will show you also that commit and all of its ancestors.
- `git log` (without any arguments) will show you the current commit (HEAD) and all of its ancestors.

If HEAD is not an ancestor of your commit it will therefore not be shown.

`git grep` is completely different. It looks at your files for a given text.
As probably no files will contain the string "9a6fe03", you will get no output.

**2. What branch is the commit on**

There are also two different kind of branches: local branches and remote branches.
 - `git branch` will only show local branches
 - `git branch -r` will only show remote branches
 - `git branch -a` will show both local and remote branches

In your case that commit is only contained in remote branches. Therefore you will only see it when specifying `-r` or `-a` (= `--all`).

**3. What branch am I on**

As you are currently at "no branch" (aka detached HEAD), so you are formally on, well, no branch. ;)

You might currently see any (possibly quite old) version of your code, or even happen to be on a commit corresponding to the HEAD of a branch.

You can try `git log --decorate --graph` - That will show any kinds of refs (like branche, tags, etc) next to your commits if there are any.